# How do I find out how many days have passed since the date saved in the SQLite table?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, julian-date

I'm writing my first Android app. I save the data to my SQLite database like this:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("mydate", System.currentTimeMillis());
    mydatabase.update("mytable", values, "id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(w.Id())});
```

Then I am to get how many days have passed from that day.
I tried this:

```
SELECT ((julianday('now') - 2440587.5)*86400000 - mydate)/1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 AS days FROM mytable
```

And get some absurd numbers.
It's because of absence of julianday() function in old Java versions I cannot get this value by simple

```
SELECT julianday('now') - mydate AS days
```

And how can I get this in old Java?

Comment: What does the java version have to do with a sqlite function?

Comment: @Shawn I want to use julianday function, but in old Java I haven't it.

Comment: But it's a Sqlite function... unless there's a java function of the same name? What class is it in?

Comment: @Shawn Yes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/JulianFields.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!
I am to save in my database every date as 'YYYY-MM-DD'.Then simply:

SELECT (strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%s', mydate)) / 86400.0 from mytable